# Getting the x and y position of each li' in a list with Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have to list with some users in it. Now via angular i am trying to get the position (x and y) of each user in the list. Not sure how to start, any help is welcome

If i type this directly into the console I get the positions of my li's:

```
$(".circular").each(function(){
                    console.log(this.offsetTop);
                });
```

But when I do it via a function in my app.js i get nothing -> http://gyazo.com/32a17fec94625aadc52d2a61a9d7c966

To get a visual, check out my code pen -> http://codepen.io/GY22/pen/bdKxee

html code:

```
<!-- START SIDEBAR -->
<div id="sidebar" ng-app="DragDrop" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="user in users" class="circular">
      <p class="initials">{{user.initials}}</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!-- END SIDEBAR -->
```

css:

```
#sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 120px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #f00;
  z-index: 33;
  margin-top: 0px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 100px
}

#userList {
  padding-bottom: 10px !important;
}

ul li {
  margin-left: -22px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: hotpink;
}

.initials {
  margin-left: 25px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

app.js:

```
var contentEditor = angular.module("DragDrop", []);

contentEditor.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.users = [{
    initials: 'GY'
  }, {
    initials: 'XX'
  }, {
    initials: 'KK'
  }, {
    initials: 'TT'
  }, {
    initials: 'AA'
  }, {
    initials: 'QQ'
  }, {
    initials: 'PP'
  }, {
    initials: 'SS'
  }, {
    initials: 'MM'
  }, {
    initials: 'RS'
  }, {
    initials: 'KL'
  }, {
    initials: 'CJ'
  }, {
    initials: 'RT'
  }, {
    initials: 'DJ'
  }, {
    initials: 'XG'
  }, {
    initials: 'XX'
  }];

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this directive

```
contentEditor.directive('custom', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        console.log(element);
      element.append("<p>y: "+element[0].offsetTop+" x: "+element[0].offsetLeft+"</p>");
    }
}
});
```

your p tag will be

```
<p class="initials" ><custom></custom>{{user.initials}}</p>
```

working pen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/doKqrP

pen that test the offset http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WvyaLL

Comment: i have one question as you can see in the list you can scroll through the users so the position will always change depending on the scroll. how to update the new scroll position?

Comment: in the second pen i log the offsettop property of the element you click and as you can see the value doesn't change.

Comment: yes but when you scroll through the list the positions of the users change normally or am i seeing it wrong ?